# Z3 query with existential quantifier return wrong result

Tags: z3, z3py

I have constructed the following

```
s=Solver()
s.add(ForAll([n],Implies(n>=0,x(n + 1) == If((x(n)==0),0,1))))
s.add(x(0) == 0)
s.add(Not(Exists([n],Implies(n>=1,(x(n)!=0)))))
```

The above query return `unsat` which did not seem to be correct?

Similarly

```
s=Solver()
s.add(ForAll([n],Implies(n>=0,x(n + 1) == If((x(n)==0),1,1))))
s.add(x(0) == 0)
s.add(Not(Exists([n],Implies(n>=1,(x(n)!=0)))))
```

The above query return `unsat` which did not seem to be correct?

Please help me to understand what is wrong in the above queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existential alone is already unsatisfiable, which might be more apparent if you replace the implication by an if-then-else:

```
not exists n :: 1 <= n ? x(n) != 0 : true
```

Thus, for any `n < 1`, you assume that

```
not exists n :: true
```

That's clearly not true.